# Microsoft Server 2008 - Limit users from copy data between sites

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have been facing a lot of issues where users will copy large amounts of data from network shares across the WAN onto their local computers.

This causes a lot of congestion on the network and we would like to somehow restrict it :)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You ought to to back and accept answers to your previous questions, Lance.

Comment: Had a quick review and had only missed two from what I can see - feel free to PM me if there is something I've missed.

Comment: Looks better now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, do they need access to these files? If so, the most you can do is put some sort of traffic shaping in place.

Alternatively, spin up a terminal server so that the users can RDP to that and access the files "locally" instead of needing to schlep them across the WAN.

Comment: The users need regular access to it and access needs to be maintained in the same way it is currently.  I don't think there is any easy straight answer for this one, but it's worth checking :)

Comment: Well then this is sort of a silly question, isn't it? "My users are doing this thing that is causing problems, but I can't change anything in the environment. Can anyone help?" :)

Comment: It is not - stupid setup. Properly would have been a DFS tree and then using partial replication between the sites, with DFS redirecting always automatically to the local copy and the users unaware where the data resides. It is not like this technology is not like - hm - 10 years old or so.

Comment: @TomTom Do you know if this sort of thing exists for Linux? We're looking at buying WAN optimisation hardware as we (currently) aren't using Windows servers apart from for RDS.

Comment: The only silly question is the one you don't ask :P There is some sort of file server role for server 2008 that handles some things that are similar to this re: disk quotas and I was hoping there might be something I had missed.  The answer is probably to have some network monitoring alerts to be notified when it happens on a network level rather than a server level.

Comment: Yes, I know - it does NOT exist on Linux. Have fun - that is one of the things makeing WIndows worthwhile.